# Is weak Lebesgue $L^{1,\infty}$ really not a Banach space?

Tags: real-analysis

I actually have a 2-part  question:

1. Can somebody please confirm that the weak Lebesgue space $L^{1,\infty} $ is not normable and hence is NOT a Banach space?  I find this not very easy to believe. But it seems to be true, i.e. it is not a Banach space. (I read in Stein's book on Fourier Analysis that the Lorentz space $L^{1,q }$ is not a Banach space for any $1\leq q\leq \infty$. But I actually think that  $L^{1,1}=L^1$ is a Banach space, right?)
2. Is this easy to show that it is not a Banach space? When I try to find a norm for weak $L^{p,\infty}$ I get a $(p-1)$ in a denominator, so that you get a blow-up as $p$ tends to 1. But I don't consider this a proof. I want to actually prove this.

Comment: Wikipedia says that the triangle inequality does not hold. For $L^p, p < 1$, one usually looks at some characteristic functions which violate triangle inequality. Perhaps that might work here too.

Comment: Yes, true, for $p<1$ the space $L^p$ is not a Banach space.  But my question is not about $L^p$ spaces but about weak $L^p$ spaces, the $L^{p,\infty}$ spaces, which are definitely Banach spaces for $p>1$. However, it seems that for end-point $p=1$ there is no norm.

Comment: I finally found an example in Stein's book. He also makes it clear that $L^{1,1} $ is not included in his example. I am not quite satisfied with this (counter)-example. Is there any other way to see this?  This would help me.

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with the counterexample?

Comment: As far as simply "proving" the point, the example is fine. WHat I am really not satisfied about is my own intuition. For example, would it be correct to say that $L^{1,q}$ for $q>1$ is not a Banach algebra because $L^1$ is the end-point case for the $L^p$ spaces to be normable, and that for $q>1$ we are making the space larger and hence going marginally past the endpoint (i.e. logarithmically) ?  After all, we know that the weak spaces are larger than their strong counterparts. At the end-point space $L^1$ you cannot make the space larger without losing normability. Is this right?